# How to check if a folder has sub folders using glob?

Tags: php

I have a dir TestRoot with two folder: TestFolderA, which has another folder and two files, and TestFolderB which only has one file. I am trying to check whether these folders themselves contain more folders.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

</head>

<body class="stretched">
<?php 
$root = "docs/RootTest"; 
$files = scandir($root);

 foreach($files as $file)
        {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') 
            {
                $link = $root.'//'.$file;

                if(is_dir($link)) //Check if file is a folder
                {
                    $folders = glob($link."/", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                    if(count($folders)>0)  //Check if it contains more folders
                    {
                        echo $link." ";
                        echo "Has Sub-folders ";
                    }                       
                    else
                    {
                        echo $link." ";
                        echo "None ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code the output is "docs/RootTest//TestFolderA Has Sub-folders" which is correct however I also get the output "docs/RootTest//TestFolderB Has Sub-folders" which is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tried both Rubin and Dilip's suggestions, but it still gives me the same result. Keeps behaving as if TestFolderB contains a sub-directory even though it only has files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK albeit not the way I wanted to, but after glob for some reason refuses to behave as expected I I instead opted to just scan the directory again and sorted it so that folders are first in the array. Then I just checked if the first element is a directory.

```
            if(is_dir($link))
            {
                $folders = scandir($link, 1);
                if(is_dir($link.'/'.$folders[0]))
                {
                     echo $link." ";
                    echo "Has Sub-folders "; 
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r( $dirs);
```

You can also try `glob()` followed `GLOB_ONLYDIR` option

Answer (score 2):

Change line

$folders = glob($link."/", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

to

$folders = glob($link."/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

Just added "*"

Answer (score -1):

PHP `is_dir()` Function

The is_dir() function checks whether the specified file is a directory.

This function returns TRUE if the directory exists.

```
<?php
$file = "images";
if(is_dir($file))
  {
  echo ("$file is a directory");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("$file is not a directory");
  }
?>
```

Output :

```
images is a directory
```

Comment: Thats not what he has asked.

Comment: @Rubinbhandari Can you explain me his requirement??

Comment: @Rubinbhandari as glob('*') will return all the files and folders which he already has done, he just need to check if there is any folder exist so he can do this by using is_dir() method.

Comment: he is asking how to check if a directory has subdirectory. What you are suggesting only checks whether a particular file is a directory or not